# how do I prove this inequality involving ODE solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equations: 
$$
  y' = (x^4 + y^4)^{1/4} , \quad y(0) = 1.
$$
I need to prove that: 
$$e^x\le y(x) \le 2e^x - x.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $y^4 > x^4$, then:
$$y'(x) = \sqrt[4]{y^4+x^4} < \sqrt[4]{2}y$$
And using [Gronwall's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality):
$$y(x)<y(0)\exp\left(\int_0^x \sqrt[4]{2} ds\right) \sim1.189 e^x < 2e^x - x$$
Now, what about the case $x^4 > y^4$? this can never happen. To see this, note that since $y' >1$ ($y$ is monotonic and $y(0)=1$), so that $y$ is always larger than $x$.

Comment: but why (x^4+y^4)^(1/4)<y*2^(1/4) this is true how did you prove it? what if y<x?

Comment: @user2359534 - if $y>x>1$, then $y^4 > x^4$, so $(x^4+y^4)^{1/4} < (2y^4)^{1/4} = 2^{1/4}y$

Comment: ok but iam asking if y<x its not true!!

Comment: @user2359534 - see my updated answer.